# GitVersion: Copyright attribute missing when publishing a single file with *GenerateAssemblyInfo* set to *false*

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, csproj, gitversion

I am using *GitVersion* in my WPF-project. When publishing my app I use profile setting ***Produce single file*** which I want to stick to. Publish only runs successfully if I set im my *.csproj*-file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I also have set the *Copyright* information in my *.csproj*-file:

```
<Copyright>Copyright © ...</Copyright>
```

---

- With *GenerateAssemblyInfo* set to ***true*** I can read the
  *Copyright* attribute in my code by *reflection*:

  ```
   var copyRightAttribute = (AssemblyCopyrightAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AssemblyCopyrightAttribute));
  ```

  Also in file-details it is visible:

  [image: file-details with copyright]

---

- With *GenerateAssemblyInfo* set to ***false*** publishing the Singe
  file runs successfully but Copyright is missing in code and in file
  details.

---

How can I have all at the same time?

1. Use GitVersion AND
2. publish a Single file AND
3. access Copyright attribute in code AND
4. see Copyright in file-details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disable automatic `AssemblyInfo` generation,
then you will need to include an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file yourself into your project,
holding the `AssemblyCopyrightAttribute` and others.

The ones in the `.csproj` file will not be considered anymore when it contains an `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`.

Note that this also includes the version numbers and more.

---

An `AssemblyInfo.cs`  example:

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Your Copyright Goes Here")]

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Your Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Your Description")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0")]
```

Comment: I did not know that  AssemblyInfo.cs still works when GenerateAssemblyInfo set to false. Thank you for the explanation. Your solution works great!!